# Test for monotonic trend in group means

Tags: statistical-significance, trend, levenes-test

I have dozens of groups of an observed variable. The number of observations in each group varies and the variance between groups is different. The mean of each group is the variable of interest. The groups have a rank 1,2,...,k.

I need a test of whether the mean increases, decreases, or stays the same as the rank increases.

If these values were just observed values I would use a Spearman Rank Correlation or a non-parametric like Wilcoxon signed-rank test. However, I think there must be some test that takes into account that these group means have variances and different sized samples.

I have a similar problem where the variable of interest is the variance (not the mean of the groups as above). For this other problem I'm using a Levene-type test for a trend in group variances. Gastwirth, Gel, Miao (2009).

Any help you can offer is greatly appreciated. Thank you.